# Strongly typed event listener function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to build a function to add an event listener that uses the provided event name to check if the provided handler function is handling the correct event. Consider the bellow code snippet.

(Context: this is for a React hook but the question is about typescript typings so removed the React specific code.)

```js
type Events = HTMLElementEventMap & WindowEventMap & DocumentEventMap;
type EventKey = keyof Events;
type ListenerElements = HTMLElement | Window | Document;

const useEventListener = <K extends EventKey>(
  event: K,
  handler: (event: Events[K]) => void,
  element: ListenerElements = window
) => {
  element.addEventListener(event, handler); // <-- Error
};

export default useEventListener;
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFAEgFQLIAyMANhALZLDyV4CGYUAZFAOoCWiAJgPYDu1yOg2YARbgGMArhWQDgQgNwAoUJFgJkAaQggMUANY7uAM3WUUy1dAJsUwJBABOJcub25CLmcCgAfVhw8vH5QYlLeykri3Ih2UJIoEHI2dg6OegA8mlAQAB72XGhy2iAAfAAUSlA5GsAAXFCaADRVUAAWtFykjg3lELUNcigA2poAugCUGKVQcNxsnC3VEKTeDSkFTl5umLyBfEpT6DMA3q0rrsgAdLScnMm2m459tU3tnZzdE8oAvpF5YG4jh8nAgxlokmIPgSSVqGzSCiAA)

Usage would be like:

```js
const exampleHandler = (event: MouseEvent) => console.log(event);
useEventListener("click", exampleHandler); // Correct

const exampleErroneusHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(event);
useEventListener("click", exampleErroneusHandler); // Error
```

The above snippet provides the following error:

> Argument of type '(event: Events[K]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
> Type '(event: Events[K]) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'evt' are incompatible.
> Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'Events[K]'.
> Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'Event & ClipboardEvent & UIEvent & AnimationEvent & MouseEvent & InputEvent & FocusEvent & ... 21 more ... & StorageEvent'.
> Property 'clipboardData' is missing in type 'Event' but required in type 'ClipboardEvent'.(2345)

One fix would be using a less specific Event instead of Events[K]

```js
handler: (event: Event) => void,
```

Is there a way to implement this without resorting to the less specific Event type?

(The title is quite clumsy, might try to make better)

Comment: If this is React I would suggest using useEffect inside of the hook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://43081j.com/2020/11/typed-events-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Basically your type checking works, just cast the handler as a `EventListener`. Your `exampleErroneusHandler` handles `KeyboardEvent`'s. While the validation of your types only allow `MouseEvent`handlers as `click`handlers can only accept `MouseEvent`s.

Do I understand, you want to have the validation on the keys of the EventMaps? As your current setup, does exactly what you ask. I believe you should rephrase the question to `build a generic function which validates if the event name is allowed for a given event handler`.

This solves your issue

```
type Events = HTMLElementEventMap & WindowEventMap & DocumentEventMap;
type ListenerElements = HTMLElement | Window | Document;

function useEventListener<E extends Events[keyof Events]>(
  event: keyof Pick<Events, {[K in keyof Events]: Events[K] extends E ? K : never}[keyof Events]>,
  handler: (event: E) => void,
  element: ListenerElements = window
) {
  element.addEventListener(event, handler as EventListener);
};

const exampleHandler = (event: MouseEvent) => console.log(event);
useEventListener("click", exampleHandler); // Correct

const exampleErroneusHandler = (event: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(event);
useEventListener("click", exampleErroneusHandler); // Argument of type '"click"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"keydown" | "keypress" | "keyup"'.ts(2345)
```

Used the following resource
[TypeScript Essentials: Conditionally Filter Types](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/typescript-essentials-conditionally-filter-types-488705bfbf56)

Answer (score 0):

**@W.S.**, Thank you for such a great answer! It seems we can do even better to infer event type to create `useEventListener` hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";


type Events = HTMLElementEventMap & WindowEventMap & DocumentEventMap & MediaQueryListEventMap;

type ListenerElements = Document | HTMLElement | MediaQueryList | Window;

export const useEventListener = <
  E extends Events[keyof Events],
  Type extends keyof Pick<Events, { [K in keyof Events]: Events[K] extends E ? K : never }[keyof Events]>,
>(
  element: ListenerElements | undefined,
  type: Type,
  handler: (event: Events[Type]) => void,
  options?: AddEventListenerOptions | boolean,
) => {
  const savedHandler = useRef(handler);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler;
  }, [handler]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject = event => savedHandler.current(event as never);

    element?.addEventListener(type, listener, options);

    return () => {
      element?.removeEventListener(type, listener, options);
    };
  }, [type, element, options]);
};
```

So we can easily use it as follows:

```
// event parameter type is inferred as "KeyboardEvent" and
// we do not need to specify its type to access "code" field.
useEventListener(window, "keydown", event => console.log(event.code));
```